# How to define an object field in GraphQLObjectType?

Tags: mongoose, graphql, mongoose-schema, graphql-js, express-graphql

So I'm trying to create a User collection in MongoDB and make queries to it using GraphQL and mongoose.

I've created my user schema in the path 'pathToServer\server\models\user.js' and it looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
    },
    email: String,
    password: String,
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And I've created a GraphQL type, currently I have it in the path 'pathToServer\server\schema\types\user.js' and it looks like this:

```
const graphql = require('graphql');

const {GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLList, GraphQLInt, GraphQLID, GraphQLString, GraphQLSchema, GraphQLNonNull} = graphql;

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLID},
        email: {type: GraphQLString},
        name: new GraphQLObjectType({
            firstName: {type: GraphQLString},
            lastName: {type: GraphQLString}
        })
    })
});

module.exports = UserType;
```

Finally I have the GraphQL schema with the queries and mutation in the path 'pathToServer\server\schema\schema.js' :

```
const graphql = require('graphql');

const {GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLList, GraphQLInt, GraphQLID, GraphQLString, GraphQLSchema, GraphQLNonNull} = graphql;

const User = require('../models/user');

const UserType = require('./types/user');

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                id: {
                    type: GraphQLID
                }
            },
            resolve(parent, args){
                return User.findById(args.id);
            }
        },
        users: {
            type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
            resolve(parent, args){
                return User.find({})
            }
        }
    }
})

const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        addUser: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                name: {
                    firstName: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                    lastName: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)}
                },
                email: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                password: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)}
            },
            resolve(parent, args){
                let user = new User({
                    name: args.name,
                    email: args.email,
                    password: args.password,
                });

                return user.save();
            }
        }
    }
})


module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery,
    mutation: Mutation
})
```

The problem is that it throws me an error whenever I start the server saying:

```
Error: Must provide name.
    at invariant (pathToServer\server\node_modules\graphql\jsutils\invariant.js:19:11)
    at new GraphQLObjectType (pathToServer\server\node_modules\graphql\type\definition.js:499:66)
    at fields (pathToServer\server\schema\types\user.js:10:15)
    at resolveThunk (pathToServer\server\node_modules\graphql\type\definition.js:370:40)
    at defineFieldMap (pathToServer\server\node_modules\graphql\type\definition.js:532:18)
    at GraphQLObjectType.getFields (pathToServer\server\node_modules\graphql\type\definition.js:506:44)
    at typeMapReducer (pathToServer\server\node_modules\graphql\type\schema.js:232:38)
    at pathToServer\server\node_modules\graphql\type\schema.js:239:20
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at typeMapReducer (pathToServer\server\node_modules\graphql\type\schema.js:232:51)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at new GraphQLSchema (pathToServer\server\node_modules\graphql\type\schema.js:122:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (pathToServer\server\schema\schema.js:79:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

Maybe I don't have the name field correctly defined? I think that it may be treated differently since the name field in my model is an object containing fields firstName and lastName.

Can you take a look, please?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
I've edit the user type from

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLID},
        email: {type: GraphQLString},
        name: new GraphQLObjectType({
            firstName: {type: GraphQLString},
            lastName: {type: GraphQLString}
        })
    })
});
```

to

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLID},
        email: {type: GraphQLString},
        name: {
            firstName: {type: GraphQLString},
            lastName: {type: GraphQLString}
        }
    })
});
```

Now the server starts, but it gives me this error in graphiql:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The type of User.name must be Output Type but got: undefined.\n\nThe type of Mutation.addUser(name:) must be Input Type but got: undefined."
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were on the right track with your original attempt. Part of the problem is that the type you're passing to the `name` field of your `UserType` needs to be fully defined. That is, it needs not only a `fields` property but also a `name` property itself. The other issue is that `User.name` needs to have its type set explicitly as a property. For readability and reuse, I would make your NameType a separate variable:

```
const NameType = new graphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Name',
  fields: () => ({
    firstName: { type: GraphQLString },
    lastName: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
})

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
    name: { type: NameType }
  })
})
```

Comment: The only problem now it is with the mutation. I got an error saying "The type of Mutation.addUser(name:) must be Input Type but got: UserName."   Does it mean that for the mutation name argument I need to create a separate GraphQL type, but this time instead of GraphQLObjectType to use GraphQLInputObjectType. Is this the correct aproach?

Comment: Yup, GraphQLObjectType cannot be used for GraphQLInputObjectType and vice versa. Please mark the answer as accepted if you found it helpful :)